# Combination of WPF DataTrigger and EventTrigger isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger, eventtrigger

I have a little question about my code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status.IsObjectSaving}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty   = "Opacity"
                            From                        ="1"
                            To                          = "0"
                            BeginTime                   = "0:0:0"
                            Duration                    = "0:0:2" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty   = "Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When my object would be saved so the grid should be open an show some information. When I start the program for the first time it works, but the second time it doesn't work. So I hope you can help me.

Thanks Daniel

p.s. sorry for my horrible english!

---

Thanks for answering! I tried to set the values with the following code:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status.IsObjectSaving}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty   = "Opacity"
                    From                        = "0"
                    To                          = "1"
                    BeginTime                   = "0:0:0"
                    Duration                    = "0:0:2" />
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty   = "Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                        Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty   = "Opacity"
                    From                        = "1"
                    To                          = "0"
                    BeginTime                   = "0:0:2"
                    Duration                    = "0:0:2" />
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty   = "Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                        Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

But it's not working. So can you help me to modify the code in a right way?

thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Animations change values with higher [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), once the visibility is changed that way the trigger will not be able to modify it. You can replace the setter with an animation (enter and exit actions), that way they have the same precedence.